# Many to Many select with grouped information in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I'm stuck in this problem all day long:

- many to many relationship

  - modules (id, name, description)
  - employees (id, name, born_date, gender, etc)
  - employees_modules

But, **employees_modules** not have just the foreign key... have other fields too:

- module_id
- employee_id
- classroom (varchar)
- enrolled (boolean)
- presence (boolean)
- away (boolean)
- other flag
- whatever

So... **In one query I need...**

- List with **all modules** +
- **how many employees** belongs to that module
- **how many classrooms** belongs to that module (but class **is just a string**)
- **how many employees are present**, etc

So... my problems are...

1. How to count **how many classrooms (string column)** belongs to each module - in raw sql I need to group classerooms and then count.
2. How to pass a where condition to a many to many relationship

---

### Structure

#### Model

- Module.php
- Employee.php
- EmployeeModule.php

---

*Sorry for my english, please fix for me...*

Comment: I can't understand what the `class (VARCHAR)` is and how should you count it. It seems to me that X number of modules will have X number of classes. Explain please

Comment: @Stichoza class = classes = school = course. It's a description field.

Comment: Do you mean distinct value in "count of classes"?

Comment: @Stichoza Yes... in ONE query I need: module id and name, classerooms qty in for this module and other calculations. But I don't known how to do a simple select + a sub-select with a groupBy and count (of this reuslt)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [how to access Laravel pivot table extra fields](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) and then use [wherePivot](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L76-L103) method to filter them.